# Linking projects C++ Cygwin

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, cygwin

I have a problem with linking my projects with Eclipse. The linking goed perfect, but everytime I get the same error:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Dierentuin_test ****

make all 
makefile:43: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

I tried everything, and googled a lot.

I'm using Cygwin in Eclipse and work on a Windows PC. The project works fine without linking, but I really need to link the projects.

I added the .o-files to the `Miscellaneous` and the `includes`.

I know there is something wrong with `C:/` but I don't not know where to edit. The error occur in the file `objects.mk` where all the .o-files added as `USER_OBJS`.

Hope you could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message:

```
makefile:43: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

tells you that at line 43 of the makefile (normally named `Makefile`) has a problem. Look there, and google with what you find there.

---

- Do you have the target listed on this line more than once in the makefile?
- Some voices on the internet say it might have to do with path separators (Windows vs. Unix way) (e.g. replacing C:/... with C:\... )
- In some german blogs they've seen DevC++ polluting Makefiles with error messages

Comment: I know, and I already did. The line #43: `Dierentuin_test.exe: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)`, nothing really specific

Comment: Make sure cygwin make is executed. If you have other development tools installed, remove them from the %PATH% to see if their own packaged MAKE binaries are the problem. E.g. Borland tools and FreePascal/Lazarus also come with own make's.